# fullCalendar Adding Specific Fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, fullcalendar

I would like to add specific fields into `fullCalendar.` For example:
Standard `fullCalendar` has a `title` field. I want to add more fields and I will accomplish this using `Bootstrap Modal`. For example: I have three specific fields, `Name`, `Mail`, `Status`. I would like to add these fields into calendar. They cannot be display directly in the calendar. But if I click the added Event, I want to display them in the `Bootstrap Modal`. How can I do that?

If I put them into `fullCalendar`, how can I get information to Bootstrap Modal with clicking Event? (All information Get&Set will use DB)

I linked my Modal with fullCalendar in here.

`$('#myModal').modal(); // in fullCalendar script`

But the script has a code ;

```
if (title) { 
calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent', { 
title: title, 
start: start, 
end: end, 
allDay: allDay },
 true // make the event "stick" ); }
```

How can I add different field? I searched everywhere but I didn't find exactly what I want.

Comment: Could you describe what you have done so far? And if you could include the minimum amount of code describing the problem?

Comment: from what i understand, you will have to make changes in your fullcalendar library a bit, but doing it dynamically is not feasible.

Comment: No changes to the fullCalendar library are needed. You can pass any custom fields you want in your JSON feed, and access those fields as part of the `event` in fullCalendar. In the `evetnClick`, just replace the text of `Name`,`Mail`, and `Status` fields with the values for the event... `$('#nameIdField').html(event.Name);`, etc.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev Thanks for your help. I solved the problem by doing what you said.